# Cannot find resource running the application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a wpf library with a windows and some views. That views have several image controls and those images are in resources folder, with build action resource and do not copy to output directory.

I have in the "first view" a reference like this:

```
Source="/Controls;component/Resources/image.png"
```

Then I have another application project that uses Controls as reference, it has a main windows that launch the "first view" of the controls library.
When I debug the application, it's ok, everything is fine.
But, when I go to the bin/debug or bin/release folder, and I execute the application from there, double click on .exe, it throws me an System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension:

"Cannot find resource 'resources/image.png'"

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help zack, I've already tried to use that uri but finally my problem seems to be the name of the image, wich has some simbols.

The name of the resource was remember_item[306].png, at the time I rename that image to remember.png, the problem is gone.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 pack://application:,,,/assembleName;component/icons/addedtofavourites.png
```